# How to Pass NetworkCredentials to the Src of an Iframe?

Tags: iframe, src, networkcredentials

I've got an iframe like this:

I'd need to pass NetworkCredentials which is required by the src site to this iframe, how is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was possible only by passing via query string.